# field_create_field enable chosen

Tags: 7, entities

I am using field_create_field and field_create_instance to create a taxonomy_autocomplete field in a rules action.

[image]

Can anyone help me enable chosen by default for these fields?

```
$vocab = '[vocabulary:machine-name]';

$field = array(
  'field_name' => 'field_termref_' . $vocab,
  'type' => 'taxonomy_term_reference',
  'settings' => array(
    'allowed_values' => array(
      array(
        'vocabulary' => $vocab,
        'parent' => 0
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
field_create_field($field);

$instance = array(
    'field_name' => 'field_termref_' . $vocab,
    'entity_type' => 'node',
    'label' => '[vocabulary:name]',
    'bundle' => 'product',
    'required' => false,
    'widget' => array(
        'type' => 'taxonomy_autocomplete'
    ),
    'display' => array(
        'default' => array('type' => 'hidden'),
        'teaser' => array('type' => 'hidden')
    )
);

field_create_instance($instance);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using devels dpm function i managed to find the correct name of the setting, so the following now works...

```
$vocab = '[vocabulary:machine-name]';

$field = array(
  'field_name' => 'field_termref_' . $vocab,
  'type' => 'taxonomy_term_reference',
  'cardinality' => -1,
  'settings' => array(
    'allowed_values' => array(
      array(
        'vocabulary' => $vocab,
        'parent' => 0
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
field_create_field($field);

$instance = array(
    'field_name' => 'field_termref_' . $vocab,
    'entity_type' => 'node',
    'label' => '[vocabulary:name]',
    'bundle' => 'product',
    'required' => false,
    'widget' => array(
        'type' => 'options_select',
        'settings' => array(
           'apply_chosen' => 1
        )
    ),
    'display' => array(
        'default' => array('type' => 'hidden'),
        'teaser' => array('type' => 'hidden')
    )
);
```